# Android using Firebase Build APK working fine but release APK crashes

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {
static ArrayList<String> images;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Gallery");

        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Gallery.this, R.color.white));
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Gallery.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.show();
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        final boolean isconnected = info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(Gallery.this);
        if (Firebase.getDefaultConfig().isPersistenceEnabled() == false)   //check if persistence is enabled or disbled
            Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        String URL = "someurl";
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase(URL);
        final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Gallery.this, images);

        final Firebase imagefolder = firebase.child("imagesfolder");
        imagefolder.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    images.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

}
}

**this is the crash report from android device monitor**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Something went wrong, please report to
>   support@firebase.com
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: You need to update SHA1 Certificat from releases apk using keystore.jks file in firebase console for your app

Comment: SHA1 is already updated .Errors remains same

Answer (score 0):

**The error is resolved by using DatabaseReference class instead of using Firebase**

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase=database.getReference().child("imagesfolder");
    final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Gallery.this, images);
     mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    images.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```